# Wolfram Player Behavior Issues in InputField Saved as an Enterprise CDF

Tags: inputfield, enterprise-cdf, enterprise

I want to enter a code in the form of StandardForm in InputField. And I want to print out the calculation result for the input code.

```
DynamicModule[{}, 
Manipulate[ Column@{ Style[in, Gray], ToExpression@in},  
Style[Control@{{in, "Plot[x,{x,-1,1}]" }, InputField, 
 ImageSize -> {300, 50}}, 20], AppearanceElements -> None]]
```

[image]

I want to enter the code in InputField without quotation marks ("code").

Of course, I know the following solutions.

```
DynamicModule[{in = "Plot[x,{x,-1,1}]" }, 
Manipulate[ Column@{ InputField[Dynamic@in, Boxes, ImageSize -> {300, 50}], 
Style[in, Gray], ToExpression@in},AppearanceElements -> None]]
```

[image]

However, this does not work normally in Wolfram Player when stored as an Enterprise CDF.
Saving the first method as an Enterprise CDF works well in Wolfram Player.

[image]

What I want is to save as an Enterprise CDF and make it work well in Wolfram Player. Is there any way to remove quotation marks ("code")?

Comment: It will be hard to find someone with access to enterprise CDFs. Can you explain what do you mean by `DynamicModule` does not work there?  Also, does this work for you: `Manipulate[Column@{DisplayForm@in, ToExpression@in}, 
 Control@{{in, "Plot[x,{x,-1,1}]"}, InputField[#, Boxes, ##2] &}]`?

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. Dynamic Module is not the part you need now. The code you presented did not run well in Wolfram Player when saved as an Enterprise CDF.

Comment: 'does not work' or 'did not run well' is not very specific...

Comment: I'm sorry. My explanation was insufficient. The following video shows a file saved as an Enterprise CDF operating in Wolfram Player.  

https://youtu.be/7p4VIlEyi0M

Comment: @Kuba Oh, didn't know `InputField` owns a 3rd argument. What's its usage? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @xzczd It does not, I've added `##2` for options.

Comment: @Kuba Er… how to set option in this case? Typing e.g. `1 + 1, Appearance -> "Framed"` in the input field doesn't work. Update: Oh, I see, `Control@{{in, "Plot[x,{x,-1,1}]"}, Appearance -> "Framed",   InputField[#, Boxes, ##2] &}` :)

Comment: What I want to implement is to enter the Mathematica code in InputField, and express the input and output in Manipulate. Of course, Wolfram Player has limitations on InputField input and operation. However, I have an Enterprise CDF license. Enterprise CDF can enter a string in InputField. However, there were unexpectedly many problems. It must be expressed in quotation marks to be executed, and input/output is broken when inputted in StandardForm format. Most people don't own Enterprise CDFs, so it's hard to show all this. Thank you for your help here so far.