# How to maintain the input form of InputField?

Tags: front-end, evaluation, dynamic, inputfield

I created a `Manipulate` with `InputField`:

```
Manipulate[Column[{  Row[{"in : ", Defer@in}], Row[{"out : ", in}] }],  
Control@{in, 1 + 1}, AppearanceElements -> None]
```

But the output is not what I want:

[image]

The desired output is:

[image]

i.e. if I type `1+1`, I want `InputField`  to keep the unevaluated `1+1`, and get `1+1` for `in` and `2` for `out`.

How can I achieve the goal?

Comment: See the third item of the first point in [the documentation of `InputField`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputField.html)

Comment: You need to use String or Boxes field, which you already know so the question is, what's wrong with them?

Comment: To be more specific, @Kuba's solution in [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/292831/wolfram-player-behavior-issues-in-inputfield-saved-as-an-enterprise-cdf#comment727197_292831) already answers your question, please read it carefully.

Answer (score 3):

This is the idiomatic way:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[
  {
   InputField[Dynamic[in], Hold[Expression]],
   Dynamic[in],
   Dynamic[HoldForm @@ in],
   Dynamic[ReleaseHold@in]
   }
  ],
  {{in, Hold[1 + 1]},
   Function[
    InputField[#, Hold[Expression]]
   ]
  }
 ]
```

I did two input fields to illustrate the principle. I'm not actually sure if there's a better way to do the control specification in the 2nd argument of Manipulate, but this is how you do an input field for expressions. You can also use `DynamicModule` to localize `in` and just forget about `Manipulate`.

Comment: Those `Dynamic`s in `Column` can be removed :) .

Comment: Thank you for your idea.
I tried to input Plot[Sin[x^2],{x,-3,3}] in InputForm and StandardForm formats.
Of course, it works very well in Mathematica.
However, files saved as Enterprise CDF will not work with Wolfram Player. When I enter the code above, it is expressed as $Failed. I understood that InputField has no input limit in Enterprise CDF. But that doesn't feel the case now.

Comment: @xzczd True, but compartmentalising dynamics is usually a good idea (at least on desktop) and it generalises more easily to the case without using `Manipulate` .

Answer (score 2):

Expand the comment to an answer. Based on the solution in [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/292831/wolfram-player-behavior-issues-in-inputfield-saved-as-an-enterprise-cdf#comment727197_292831):

```
Manipulate[
 Grid@{{"in:", DisplayForm@in}, {"out:", ToExpression@in}}, 
 {{in, 1 + 1 // MakeBoxes}, InputField[#, Boxes] &}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Hoony This is just strange. Sadly I don't have access to Enterprise CDF so cannot test. Have you consulted WRI about whether it's a bug of Wolfram Player or not?

Comment: I agree. I'm not sure if this issue is a bug or a limited feature that also exists in Enterprise CDF. If you want to actively test, I can also send you the Enterprise Notebook file. This is a file that can be modified in Mathematica and tested in Wolfram Player.

Comment: @Hoony I'd suggest upload it to e.g. github and add the download link to the body of question. (If the file isn't that large, you can even open it with a text editor and copy the content to the body of question. )

Comment: The answer sent by Wolfram is said to be normal, but I don't understand it. The following are the Wolfram answers.    
  It appears the program is behaving correctly. There is no argument for the SuperscriptBox. The FractionBox would have to be the first argument. Our developers will all tell you the way to work with boxes is to use ToBoxes if you want the expression to expression to evaluate and MakeBoxes otherwise.

Comment: @Hoony Well, the support staff may make mistakes (yeah I have such experience)… so we need to convince the support staff now. I'd suggest emphasizing the code just works fine in _Mathematica_ but not in Enterprise CDF.

Comment: http://naver.me/xn6587A4 

Attach the Enterprise DF file. Mathematica can modify and execute code, and both Enterprise CDF functions work in Wolfram Player. Please test it out. For example, the code "Plot[x,{x,-1,1}" works in Mathematica. However, it doesn't work in Wolfram Player.

Comment: @Hoony I've tried saving `Manipulate[x, {{x, "test"}, InputField}]` in the CDF file. It works as expected in _Mathematica_, but when opening it with _Wolfram Player 13.3_, or _Preview for Wolfram Player_ of _Mathematica 12.3 & 13.3_, the manipulator doesn't response. Not sure if it's bug or limitation of CDF file, let's wait for the clarification of WRI support.

Comment: I think. Even if it is Enterprise CDF, simple TEXT is possible, but CODE TEXT seems to be limited.That's why I tried a roundabout way of writing CODE TEXT in quotation marks. But I tried to solve it because I couldn't be bothered to use quotation marks. Thank you for your attention and explanation.

Comment: I posted a related question. Can you take a look at it?   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/292977/

Answer (score 0):

Does the following what you want?

```
Manipulate[Column[{Row[{"in : ",
     in}], Row[{"out : ", in // ReleaseHold}]}], 
 Control@{in, HoldForm[1 + 1]}, AppearanceElements -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is a bit unstable. One may easily delete the `HoldForm` when editing the input field.

Comment: What I want to implement is to enter the Mathematica code in InputField, and express the input and output in Manipulate. Of course, Wolfram Player has limitations on InputField input and operation. However, I have an Enterprise CDF license. Enterprise CDF can enter a string in InputField. However, there were unexpectedly many problems. It must be expressed in quotation marks to be executed, and input/output is broken when inputted in StandardForm format. Most people don't own Enterprise CDFs, so it's hard to show all this. Thank you for your help here so far.