# Problems that occur when converting to PDF files using NotebookPrint

Tags: front-end, export, string-manipulation, pdf-format, standardform

I made a string expressed in `StandardForm` format.

```
str = "Plot[Sin[\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \
\(2\)]\)]+\!\(\*SqrtBox[FractionBox[\(x\), \(2\)]]\),{x,0,3}]";
```

[image]

And I want to save this as a PDF file.

```
NotebookPrint[ str, StringJoin[NotebookDirectory[],   "tset1.pdf"]]
```

If you open the PDF file, it doesn't look like `StandardForm`.

[image]

Can I use `NotebookPrint` to save PDF files in `StandardForm` format?

If I use `Export`, I can save PDF files in the desired form.

```
Export[ StringJoin[NotebookDirectory[], "tset2.pdf"], str]
```

However, there is one big problem with this. If the string is very long and is one page long, the page cannot be divided.

I want to make a PDF file so that I can keep the `StandardForm` format and separate pages for long sentences.

Comment: How about `str = "Plot[Sin[\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \
\(2\)]\)]+\!\(\*SqrtBox[FractionBox[\(x\), \(3\)]]\),{x,0,3}]";
NotebookPrint[str // MakeExpression // Apply@HoldForm, "tset1.pdf"]`?

Comment: Thank you, it works very well. Your answer made it possible for me to proceed to the next level. Thank you again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn the comment to an answer:

```
NotebookPrint[str // MakeExpression // Apply@HoldForm, "tset1.pdf"]
"tset1.pdf" // SystemOpen
```